# ElasticSearch: how to mix terms query with wildcard

Tags: search, lucene, wildcard, elasticsearch

Say, I have the following query: 'document spreadsheet app*'. I want to construct the query dictionary which is equivalent to this type of query '_search?q=_all:document+spreadsheet+app*'. Say, query_words_list = ['document', 'spreadsheet', 'app']. I tried this:

```
{
  'query': {
     'terms': {
        '_all': query_words_list[:-1] + [query_words_list[-1] + '*'],
     }
   }
}
```

However, if you compare results of two queries, they are not equivalent. Any hints what query dictionary equivalent to '_search?q=_all:document+spreadsheet+app*' can look like? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `q` [parameter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/uri-request.html) is equivalent to [Query String Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html).

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up constructing the bool query with several term queries (where the last term is a wildcard) in the should clauses.